Why is my server drop-down menu not populating?
I'm having trouble understanding why my server array keeps getting overwritten.
In my run_practice.py file:
options = SwaggerUIOptions(
swagger_ui_config={
"displayRequestDuration": True,
"operationsSorter": "alpha",
"tagsSorter": "alpha",
"tryItOutEnabled": True,
}
)

app = FlaskApp(__name__,
specification_dir=f"{repo_root}/practice/spec",
)

# Load the OpenAPI spec
spec_path = f"{repo_root}/practice/spec/together.json"

def load_spec():
    with open(spec_path) as spec_file:
        return json.load(spec_file)
    print('what') ## both of these print statements aren't printing
    print('spec file: ', spec_file.servers)
class SpecResource(Resource):
    def get(self):
        return load_spec()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    api_running = True
    token_refresh()
    initialize_behave_queue()
    initialize_checker_queue()

    output = os.system(f"yamlinc {repo_root}/practice/spec/main_spec.yaml")
    # Local runs
    if os.path.exists(f"{repo_root}/practice/main_spec.inc.yaml"):
        shutil.move(f"{repo_root}/practice/main_spec.inc.yaml", f"{repo_root}/practice/spec/main_spec.inc.yaml")
    # Resolve parameter and response references into a single spec file
    os.system(f"swagger-combine {repo_root}/practice/spec/main_spec.inc.yaml -o {repo_root}/practice/spec/together.json")

    # Map each environment to the SpecResource with a unique endpoint name
    for env_name in env_map:
        app.add_api(f"{repo_root}/practice/spec/together.json",
                    strict_validation=True,
                    options=options,
                    base_path=f"/{env_name}"
                    )
    
    scheduler.add_job(func=token_refresh, trigger="interval", hours=5)
    scheduler.start()
    atexit.register(lambda: scheduler.shutdown())

    app.run(host="0.0.0.0", port=port)

I tried specifying servers in my main_spec and together files:
My main_spec.yaml file:
servers:
  - url: /path1/ui
    description: Path1
  - url: /path2/ui
    description: Path2`

And in my together.json file:
`  "servers": [
    {
      "url": "/path1/ui",
      "description": "Path1"
    },
    {
      "url": "/path2/ui",
      "description": "Path2"
    }
  ],

But when I run my project and look at localhost/path1/openapi.json i see
 "servers": [
    {
      "url": "/path1"
    }
  ],

Instead of my list of servers.
Why are my server specifications being overwritten and why won't my server dropdown populate?
